# Did a Sentry integration in Java as followed. Not getting a single event on Sentry dashboard. What could be the reason?

Tags: java, sentry

```
  Sentry.init("https://a96e4f7079404e12823024df8367d521@o443980.ingest.sentry.io/5418440");
  sentry = SentryClientFactory.sentryClient();
  logWithStaticAPI();


static  void logWithStaticAPI() {
    // Note that all fields set on the context are optional. Context data is copied onto
    // all future events in the current context (until the context is cleared).

    // Record a breadcrumb in the current context. By default the last 100 breadcrumbs are kept.
    Sentry.getContext().recordBreadcrumb(
            new BreadcrumbBuilder().setMessage("User made an action").build()
    );

    // Set the user in the current context.
    Sentry.getContext().setUser(
            new UserBuilder().setEmail("hello@sentry.io").build()
    );

    // Add extra data to future events in this context.
    Sentry.getContext().addExtra("extra", "thing");

    // Add an additional tag to future events in this context.
    Sentry.getContext().addTag("tagName", "tagValue");

    /*
     This sends a simple event to Sentry using the statically stored instance
     that was created in the ``main`` method.
     */
    Sentry.capture("This is a test");

    try {
        unsafeMethod();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // This sends an exception event to Sentry using the statically stored instance
        // that was created in the ``main`` method.
        Sentry.capture(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a console application? The events are submitted in the background, does the app run long enough to flush the events?

Comment: @BrunoGarcia No its not a console application and the threads run for enough time after I create the event

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.
It actually started working after a day or so. So be patient after the integration.